# WooCommerce font color for wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

So I am using woo commerce for the first time and having some issues in trying to change the color of the font (and size) on the shopping cart and checkout page of a site I'm working on. I've used firebug but, I'm not getting anywhere with the changes. I'm sure its a simple fix but its kicking me in the arse.

Please Help

```css
body {
    background-image: none;
}

.no-featured-image-post {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}

.thumbnail-article img, .gallery-item img,
.entry-content img, .comments img,
.album-widget figure figcaption img,
.post-article.single-post .content-album-article .left figure figcaption img, .albums-container article figure figcaption img,
.videos-container article figure figcaption img,
.photos-container article figure figcaption img,
.artists-container article figure figcaption img,
.ablums-posts-right article .left figure figcaption img,
.single-event-widget figure figcaption img,
figure.event figcaption img,
.events-container article figure figcaption img,
article.event-article figure figcaption img,
.artist-widget figure figcaption img,
.top-events-albums .events-albums ul li figure figcaption > img,
.event-widget figure figcaption img, .event-widget-countdown figure figcaption img,
.top-albums-widget article figure figcaption img,
.top-rated-albums-widget article figure figcaption img,
.photos-container article figure figcaption img,
.products > li img,
.images .woocommerce-main-image img,
.images .thumbnails a img,
.widget_shopping_cart_content .product_list_widget li a img,
.woocommerce .shop_table.cart .product-thumbnail > a img,
.ablums-posts-bottom article .left figure figcaption img {
    height: auto;
}
.awaiting-moderation {
    font-style: italic;
}

.form-allowed-tags {
    display: none;
}

.post-article .content-article h1, .post-article .content-event-article h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.event-details .details p span {
    min-width: 90px;
}

.events-container article figure figcaption .min-info h4 {
    color: #fff;
}

article iframe {
    width:100%;
}

.menu {
    z-index: 99;
}

body.admin-bar {
    padding-top: 0;
}

.products > li .product-container .onsale {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(142, 68, 173, 0.8);
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 15px 0 0 15px;
}

.wpb_row {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}

.wpb_column > .wpb_wrapper .underline-bg {
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.widget .tagcloud a {
    padding: 0px 8px;
}

.wp-caption,
.wp-caption-text,
.sticky,
.gallery-caption,
.bypostauthor,
.aligncenter { }

.minimal-player .name p {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.format-audio figcaption > div,
.format-audio figcaption > p
{
    display:none !important;
}

.light-layout .dropcap {
    color: #000000;
}

.woocommerce-tabs .entry-content .comment-respond .comment-form p textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    border-color: black;
}

body.light-layout .woocommerce #payment .payment_box, body.light-layout .make-event #payment .payment_box {

 padding-bottom: 20px;
        border-color: black;
}

body.light-layout .woocommerce #payment .payment_box input[type=text], body.light-layout .make-event #payment .payment_box input[type=text],
body.light-layout .woocommerce #payment .payment_box p, body.light-layout .make-event #payment .payment_box p {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding-bottom: 0;
        font: #000;
        border-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using "font-color: #000000;" on your last selector and that's invalid CSS.

If you need font color change just use color: #000; (Also no need for six zeros since it's black)

Also, you can use a service to check your css errors http://csslint.net/

```css
.woocommerce .shop_table.cart .product-thumbnail .product-info a, .make-event .shop_table.cart .product-thumbnail .product-info a,
.woocommerce .shop_table.cart .product-price .amount, .make-event .shop_table.cart .product-price .amount, .woocommerce .shop_table.cart .product-subtotal .amount, .make-event .shop_table.cart .product-subtotal .amount,
.woocommerce .shop_table tr th, .make-event .shop_table tr th, .woocommerce .shop_table tr td, .make-event .shop_table tr td,
.woocommerce .cart-totals-container .cart_totals table th, .make-event .cart-totals-container .cart_totals table th, .woocommerce .cart-totals-container .cart_totals table td, .make-event .cart-totals-container .cart_totals table td,
.woocommerce .cart-totals-container .cart_totals table th strong, .make-event .cart-totals-container .cart_totals table th strong, .woocommerce .cart-totals-container .cart_totals table td strong, .make-event .cart-totals-container .cart_totals table td strong,
#customer_login h2,
body.light-layout .woocommerce .cart-totals-container > button,
body.light-layout .woocommerce .shop_table.cart thead th, body.light-layout .make-event .shop_table.cart thead th {
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

Add this to the bottom of your CSS file it should overide everything on the cart page.

However, my guess is that you can change the font colors in your theme. Is that a canvas theme maybe? Go to Theme Options or Appearance > Theme Options and look for Typography setting it should allow you to change font types and colors.

Comment: Thanks I've Made the changes however it didn't work. it's almost as if something is overriding it

Comment: Can you give me the link to the site so I can have a look? And also tell me which font you need changed.

Comment: Also in the code above you've changed it to "font: #000;" whereas it needs to be "color: #000;"

Comment: Sure http://www.elifemediastream.com/?page_id=2124 still have alot of work to do. but as per the client they want me to focus on the money portion blah blah blah lol

Comment: I see, well the color is black there. What exactly did you want to change to black on this page?

Comment: Well If you look on the shopping carts itemized page the font that breaks down price how many items etc is gray (I believe #e2e2e2) also on the proceed to checkout page I would like the field where you type your info (cc address etc.) to be a simple black

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108638/discussion-between-clay-and-klaudio-milankovic).